# How to delete a value from the key in python dictonary where values are stored in list

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to delete a specific element from the values of a single key.

```
adj_city = {

'WA': ['NT','SA'],
'NT': ['WA','SA','Q'],
'SA': ['WA','NT','NSW','V'],
'Q' : ['NT', 'NSW'],
'NSW': ['Q','SA','V'],
'V': ['SA','NSW']
}

for i in adj_city['WA'] :
    if(i=='NT'):
        del(i)
```

I am expecting the output as 'WA': ['SA'] but after running the above code I am not getting the output

Comment: Do you want ```NT``` removed from every list on the dictionary or just for the list under ```WA``` key?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the NT value use [remove](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html), never iterate and delete at the same time:

```
adj_city = {

'WA': ['NT','SA'],
'NT': ['WA','SA','Q'],
'SA': ['WA','NT','NSW','V'],
'Q' : ['NT', 'NSW'],
'NSW': ['Q','SA','V'],
'V': ['SA','NSW']
}

adj_city['WA'].remove('NT')

print(adj_city['WA'])
```

**Output**

```
['SA']
```

Answer (score 1):

To know why your code doesn't work, try to understand the below code:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]

for val in arr:
    del val

    try:
        val
    except NameError as e:
        print(e)

    print(arr)
```

Output:

```
name 'val' is not defined
[1, 2, 3]
name 'val' is not defined
[1, 2, 3]
name 'val' is not defined
[1, 2, 3]
```

**Observation:**

- Variable `val` is deleted (i.e. it is not available anymore) and but `arr` is untouched.

---

Simply use a list comprehension:

```
adj_city = {
    'WA': ['NT','SA'],
    'NT': ['WA','SA','Q'],
    'SA': ['WA','NT','NSW','V'],
    'Q' : ['NT', 'NSW'],
    'NSW': ['Q','SA','V'],
    'V': ['SA','NSW']
}

adj_city["WA"] = [city for city in adj_city["WA"] if city != 'NT'] 

assert adj_city == {
    'WA': ['SA'],
    'NT': ['WA','SA','Q'],
    'SA': ['WA','NT','NSW','V'],
    'Q' : ['NT', 'NSW'],
    'NSW': ['Q','SA','V'],
    'V': ['SA','NSW']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
adj_city = {
    'WA': ['NT','SA'],
    'NT': ['WA','SA','Q'],
    'SA': ['WA','NT','NSW','V'],
    'Q' : ['NT', 'NSW'],
    'NSW': ['Q','SA','V'],
    'V': ['SA','NSW']
}

adj_city["WA"] = [i for i in adj_city["WA"] if i != 'NT'] 
print(adj_city)
```

**Output:**

```
{'NSW': ['Q', 'SA', 'V'],
 'NT': ['WA', 'SA', 'Q'],
 'Q': ['NT', 'NSW'],
 'SA': ['WA', 'NT', 'NSW', 'V'],
 'V': ['SA', 'NSW'],
 'WA': ['SA']}
```

Note: Not a good practice to delete an element while iterating the object.

Comment: I guess it is OK to delete those values because the loop is iterating over the dictionary keys and the code is not touching them.

Comment: Also, I'm under the impression the OP wants to remove any ocurrency of ```NT``` on the lists, so we need a loop doing the list comprehension for every list under a key.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for

```
adj_city = {
    'WA': ['NT','SA'],
    'NT': ['WA','SA','Q'],
    'SA': ['WA','NT','NSW','V'],
    'Q' : ['NT', 'NSW'],
    'NSW': ['Q','SA','V'],
    'V': ['SA','NSW']
}

# keys where the values need to be removed
dict_keys = ['WA']

# values to be removed
unwanted_values = ['NT']

for key in dict_keys:
    try:
        adj_city[key] = [item 
                         for item in adj_city[key] 
                         if not item in unwanted_values]
    except KeyError:
        pass

print(adj_city)
```

Which yields

```
{
    'WA': ['SA'], 
    'NT': ['WA', 'SA', 'Q'], 
    'SA': ['WA', 'NT', 'NSW', 'V'], 
    'Q': ['NT', 'NSW'], 
    'NSW': ['Q', 'SA', 'V'], 
    'V': ['SA', 'NSW']
}
```